# Installation of anjuta failed in ubuntu 12.04LTS:

Tags: ubuntu, anjuta

I tried to install Anjuta IDE in Ubuntu using the "Software Center" application. The installation failed. The following sre the log details. What can I do to fix this?

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

Extracting templates from packages: 54%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

Extracting templates from packages: 54%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

Extracting templates from packages: 54%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

Extracting templates from packages: 54%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Setting up install-info (4.13a.dfsg.1-10ubuntu2) ...
/etc/environment: line 5: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
Error in function: 
Setting up install-info (4.13a.dfsg.1-10ubuntu2) ...
/etc/environment: line 5: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question. I reedited the environment variables values by following the commands:
1. gksudo gedit /etc/environment
2. set the path as the following :
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
export GNOME_SHELL_DISABLE_TFP=1

for reference please do find the link below:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texinfo/+bug/993407